How small can I make a water vortex in a bottle before surface tension and adhesion stops the effect?
first question on the forum:  I'm trying to make the smallest water vortex toy possible, where two water bottles/jugs are attached by the mouth facing each other, with a full bottle at the top and an empty one on the bottom, with a small central hole between the attached bottle openings.  Rotating the top bottle full of water creates a self-sustaining vortex, which then drains into the bottom empty bottle. You can find plenty of examples of this on YouTube. I wanted to create the smallest vortex toy I can, but am finding that due to surface tension, water does not want to travel through the small hole, and that I cannot create a vortex in the 6 mL bottle I am using, possibly due to adhesion of the water to the interior walls of the bottle.  Apparently due to surface tension and adhesion of the water there is a limit to how small you can create a vortex effect.  My question is, how can you calculate this?  Is there a way to mathematically determine how small a water vortex can be created?  I've tried surfactants to reduce the surface tension of the water, but I only wind up with sudsy water that appears to have the same surface tension as before.  Would alcohol or another fluid be a better choice?  I simply wish to create the smallest fluid vortex in a bottle that I can.
Thanks for any input.

Possible duplicate - How to reduce surface tension of water?
